# How to get image been set on radio button

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

I have some images been inserted on the left side of a radio button.

```
 <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/avatar2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/batman"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        />
```

But i need to get that image on logical part for further process.

How to do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

[getCompoundDrawables()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawables()) returns an array of drawables for the left, top, right, and bottom borders.

```
Drawable d = button.getCompoundDrawables()[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button);

rb.getButtonDrawable()
```

Returns the drawable used as the compound button image: minimum Api 19

Comment: Guess i should use another approach, since i want the app to be accessible with lower API too. Thanks thoe